# Laravel escaping partials

Tags: php, laravel, escaping

I am porting some code onto a windows machine. It works fine on Apache.

It is a Laravel project and the issue I have is that it seems Laravel or IIS-PHP is escaping special characters in my partials.

I simply use

```
<?php include partial('metadims'); ?>
```

in one of my template files however I get an error when laravel tries to render this:

```
include(C:\websites xxxx\htdocs   heme//layouts/partials/metadims.php): failed to open stream: Invalid argument
```

The full path that laravel is trying to read is:

```
c:\websites\fxxxx\htdocs\themes\layouts\partials\metadims.php
```

But clearly something is seeing the slashes as indicating a special character and attempting to pass that to Laravel.

I guess its something to do with path structure difference between Windows and Linux but I'm stuck. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the `partial()` function? (I suppose you wrote it yourself?)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you've found a bug in laravel.

Always use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, and single quotes.

Comment: True, but between double quotes it also interprets special characters. \t for example. With single quotes you won't face this.